# Does the SDK support @2x files for video

Tags: iphone, ios4

We are using the MPMoviePlayerController to control video playback, I just wanted to know (as I couldnt find any mention online) whether it took advantage of @2x files when displayed on iPod4/iPhone4, like the UIImage does

Comment: No, but you could easily create a category of MPMoviePlayerController to add a method, or even subclass it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't do it automatically like UIImage will. But you could always implement a system your self. Using a subclass, category or just in your current code before set what file is played by the movie player. So the code would be something like. If it has a retina display append @2x to the file path.

Answer (score 1):

No, @2X it's only for UIimages.